# preview frames on a custom flash player progress bar

Tags: flash, video, video-streaming

recently I built a flash video player (which loads different videos from a directory based on which xml file is loaded). anyway, I've seen this cool feature in custom flash players(HULU,youtube etc) that I'd like to implement, but don't have the slightest clue how it's done(or what it's called, which has made searching google rather difficult ).

when you roll your mouse over the videos progress bar a little box pops up and displays a frame from that point in the video.

does anyone know how to do this or can point me to some tutorials?

Comment: I would look treat that preview frame as it were just another video. On mouse over of the progress bar, you do the usual NetConnection/NetStream stuff to play the "preview" video in this small popup/preview container. Seek to the proper point, and pause playback.

Comment: would i be using the same file that i'm playing in the main viewing area,and since you're saying to use multiple netstreams is there any kind of performance issues with doing it this way?

Comment: Good points, guys (@code wombat and @Scot Chu). I should have put more thought into it, my suggestion is not performant at all!

Answer (score -1):

Sunil's answer might be a solution but would be a slow solution, IMO. I really didn't figure out how Youtube or other video players do that. But in our case, we generate a CSS sprite containing preview image of frames per video in advance. When user openes a video web page, that video's CSS sprite will be downloaded to client side, too. So when the user moves mouse along the progress bar, we'll calculate which frame the cursor is on and get that frame preview image from CSS sprite. We use CSS sprite to make sure that there's only 1 connection when Browser downloads the frame preview images. Hope this helpful.

By the way, can anyone tell me the known name of this feature? I've been asking around many people but no one knows the official name of this feature.

~~~~
EDIT @ 2012/8/15
I think I got a better and pleasant name of this function from some web pages, it's called storyboarding. This is much better than video thumbnail.

Comment: i think i read some were that youtube does that as well, but i can't confirm it. how are you generating the sprite?

Comment: CSS sprite is how YouTube does it to for their [**Storyboards**](http://www.itmashable.com/2012/01/youtube-lunched-new-player-with.html). You can view these files using Firefox with Firebugs Net Tab. The Storyboard images can not be hot-linked since they depend on the browsers cookie.

Comment: ok but how are they generated? i assume its done programatically